# Concrete5: set File thumbnail to generated image (e.g. for PDFs)

Tags: php, concrete5, concrete5-5.7

I'm using Concrete5, and I'm trying to display thumbnails for various uploaded files. While some of these might be images, the majority are PDFs.

I'm currently using:

```
<?php
$file = File::getByID($fID);
$imageHelper = Core::make('helper/image');
try {
    $imageHelper->outputThumbnail($file, 200, 200);
} catch(InvalidArgumentException $e) { ?>
    <img src='https://placehold.it/200x200'>
<?php } ?>
```

I'd much prefer to somehow create a smaller thumbnail of PDF files, for example by using ghostscript in the background. In the built-in file manager, at least a PDF icon is displayed. That would be a non-optimal option, but still better than not displaying anything to signify that we're dealing with a PDF..

How can I access the built-in thumbnails? And, more importantly, how can I properly overwrite them for certain file-types when they are uploaded?

EDIT:

I came across `$file->getThumbnailURL('type');` and created a type for my own purposes. How would you automatically generate such a thumbnail when a file is uploaded? I can likely figure out how to generate the file with plain PHP, but storing it in Concrete5 is something I'm unsure about.

Comment: I have no idea whether C5 supports this, interesting question. If it doesn't work out, you could consider taking care of the thumbnail generation yourself, generating and storing them in a separate directory.

Comment: @Pekka I did consider that for a bit.. I noticed that there is an `on_file_add` event to hook into. How would you recommend associating thumbnails with files? Create a directory structure based on the file ID? Or can I somehow set the location for custom thumbnail types? Thanks for bringing this up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, here's how I did it.

I started off by creating a new thumbnail type in the configure method of my package's controller, as follows:

```
use Concrete\Core\File\Image\Thumbnail\Type\Type;

...

public function configure($pkg) {
    ...

    $thumbnailType = new Type();
    $thumbnailType->setName(tc('ThumbnailTypeName', 'PDF Thumbnails'));
    $thumbnailType->setHandle('pdfthumbnails');
    $thumbnailType->setWidth(200);
    $thumbnailType->setHeight(200);
    $thumbnailType->save();
}
```

Then I created a class `mypackage/src/document_processing/pdfthumbnails.php` with the following contents:

```
namespace Concrete\Package\Mypackage\Src\DocumentProcessing;

use Core;
use File;
use Concrete\Core\File\Image\Thumbnail\Type\Type;

class Pdfthumbnails {

    public function processPDFThumbnails($fv) {
        $fi = Core::make('helper/file');
        $fvObj = $fv->getFileVersionObject();
        $ext = $fi->getExtension($fvObj->getFilename());
        $file = $fvObj->getFile();
        if ($ext == 'pdf') {
            $type = Type::getByHandle('pdfthumbnails');
            $basetype = $type->getBaseVersion();
            $thumbpath = $basetype->getFilePath($fvObj);

            $fsl = $file->getFileStorageLocationObject()->getFileSystemObject();
            $fre = $fvObj->getFileResource();
            // this requires sufficient permissions..
            // depending on your setup, reconsider 0777
            mkdir('application/files'.dirname($thumbpath), 0777, true);
            exec('gs -o application/files'.escapeshellarg($thumbpath).' -dPDFFitPage -sDEVICE=png16m -g200x200 -dLastPage=1 -f application/files/'.escapeshellarg($fre->getPath()));
        }
    }
}
```

And then I hooked into the `on_file_version_add` event in my package's controller:

```
use Concrete\Package\Mypackage\Src\DocumentProcessing\Pdfthumbnails;

...

    public function on_start() {
        Events::addListener('on_file_version_add', array(new Pdfthumbnails(), 'processPDFThumbnails'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be possible inside C5 after all, using [file inspectors](https://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/5.7/concepts/files):

> Any time a file is imported into Concrete5 (which happens through an instance of the File Importer class) it may be run through an optional file Inspector, which is a PHP class that can perform additional operations on files of a certain type when they're uploaded or rescanned

More information and implementation examples on file inspectors can be found [in the C5 documentation.](http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/5.6/files/metadata)

In [this Concrete5 forum discussion](https://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/customizing_c5/firing-custom-eventfile-inspection-on-pdf-upload/), someone seems to have used this feature to build exactly what you want to build, a thumbnail generator for PDFs using ImageMagick.

That user's example code does two things. First, it registers a new custom file inspector with the running C5 instance. Then, your custom inspector library is added to the project.

Comment: Nice, that looks pretty neat! Thanks. I'll try it out and will report back :)

Comment: I ended up using this to hook into the file_add_version event, and that works fine. The problem is still with actually _storing_ the generated thumbnail, though. This does not seem to be addressed there.